# What does the word "transgress" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

In a gameplay video I watched today on youtube, from a game called Dragon Quest 11, the person playing finished some kind of quest and got rewarded with some items. This is a message that popped up when they finished it.

"Success! This quest has been transgressed with finesse!"

I deduce that this means that the quest has been accomplished with in great style, but what the word "transgress" means?
I searched the dictionaries for the definition of the word "transgress" but I can't find anything that seems to correspond to the sentence above. I provided a Pro-forma definition below.

Yourfreedictionary verb "transgress":
To go beyond or over (a limit or boundary); exceed or overstep.

Comment: *Transgress* doesn't make any sense in this context.  I suspect that the person who wrote the game was not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Using the simplest definition, "to exceed:"

"Success! The quest [requirements] have been EXCEEDED with finesse!"

I presume they were trying to be cute or someone recently learned a new word. Typically, the exceeding part of transgress, is exceeding in a negative way.